# Deploying a site to GCP staging area

Tags: web, google-cloud-platform, web-deployment, staging

I am currently trying to deploy my web site to the Google Cloud Platform staging area. I can see on the app engine docs that there is a clear cut way to do so but for the compute engine I cannot seem to identify the section on `STAGING` as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/instance-life-cycle). I can find sections on Stopping and Starting, suspending and resuming, but nothing on Staging.

From what I understand I have to create a bucket but that is all I know how to do in regards to staging. Is there a way to do this while the normal site is still running? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your first sentence (I'm trying deploy to staging) makes me think you misunderstand what "staging" means in this context. You dont deploy to staging, it's just a part of the lifecycle before the instance is ready and running. However f I misunderstood your question, please elaborate more what is your plan with the staging.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko trying to push a test version of the site so it can be approved for the live site? A staging address does already exist

Comment: Right. But the documentation you linked has nothing to with a testing site. `STAGING` in this context is just a temporary state of an instance before it's ready to serve request, no matter if it's a production environment or testing environment.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko ah right I see, thanks for the very speedy response. So the Staging here is temporary and not any particular testing environment?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko ok thank you. So for making a seperate staging area I need to make a bucket at a URL and then make that public once all files are in?